# How do you breed a winter dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I've been trying to breed a winter dragon for a month using various combos cold, erstwhile and air.  Are there combos that have better chances?

Answer (score 2):

Use either:
1. Air and Glacier
2. Moss and Snow
3. Forest and Blizzard

Usually you have a better chance if your dragon's level is really high.